# Can't add PHP-mcrypt and PHP-intl extensions on Mac Os Sierra

Tags: php, magento-2.1

I tried to install `magento` 2.1.3, but during the readiness check i get an error that says that i have to install both `PHP-mcrypt` and `PHP-intl` extensions in order to proceed. I install the previous extensions from my terminal using the following commands `brew install php56-mcrypt` and `brew install php56-intl`, then i restart the apache and running the classic `phpinfo()` check to see if the extensions are installed but i can't find them. I am using the default php the came along the Sierra Os. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

1) which php
/usr/local/bin/php

2) php -v
PHP 7.1.7 (cli)

3)php -i | grep 'php.ini'
Ensure exists /etc/php.ini, if not
sudo ln -s /usr/local/etc/php/7.1/php.ini /etc/php.ini

4) brew install homebrew/php/php71-mcrypt

5) brew install homebrew/php/php71-intl

6) add to php.ini
[intl]
extension=/usr/local/opt/php71-intl/intl.so

[mcrypt]
extension=/usr/local/opt/php71-mcrypt/mcrypt.so

7) sudo apachectl restart

8) phpinfo()

Answer (score 0):

Although this isn't a Magento question really. Your problem is Apache isn't running through **brew** its running off of the local system - Mac OsX is handling it.

My recommendation would be to look at installing *[mcrypt.so](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-mcrypt-for-php-on-mac-osx-10-10-yosemite-for-a-development-server/)* and *[intl](https://codingexplained.com/operating-systems/mac/installing-php-intl-extension-os-x-mavericks)*  like the links provided, however personally, i would reconfigure your system to use brew for all actions.

This is a great walk through here:

https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-sierra-apache-multiple-php-versions

Answer (score -2):

Did you add the line `extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php56-mcrypt/5.6.x/mcrypt.so"` and `extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php56-intl/5.6.x/intl.so"` to php.ini files.