# Magento 2 install nginx php mysql dnsmasq xdebug php codesniffer on mac high sierra

Tags: magento2, php, database, nginx, xdebug

Is there any complete guide where I can see how to install

```
1. nginx
2. php (multiple version)
3. mysql
4. dnsmasq
5. xdebug
6. php codesniffer
```

on mac high sierra?

Please don't suggest Valet+ ;). 
I need flexibility to change configurations :) like we do in linux environment.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at Valet :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't add PHP-mcrypt and PHP-intl extensions on Mac Os Sierra](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154312/cant-add-php-mcrypt-and-php-intl-extensions-on-mac-os-sierra)

Comment: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/nginx